# Angular Interceptor, retry request on error

Tags: angular, angular-http, angular-httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

I would like to let the user retry a request results in an error. I display a Toast with a retry button on it and when the user clicks retry the request is sent again.

The issue I'm having is that the retried request is always cancelled

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private snackSrv: MatSnackBar) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      retryWhen(err => {
        const snackRef = this.snackSrv.open('Failed', 'retry');
        return snackRef.onAction();
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Why is it cancelled ? And in the above code isn't there a memory leak where the subscription is gonna be alive until the user clicks retry ?

Comment: Do you request again on clicking of retry? can you create stackblitz link?

Comment: have you configure the interceptor in app.module?

Comment: @Justcode yeah I do request on clicking retry, i'll make a stackblitz

Comment: @Justcode actually it seems to work here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9xziyu

Comment: @Ced yes, seems working, what error code your receiving from server?

Comment: @Justcode well 500 and on the second try also in the stackblitz. In my own code I have 500 then request cancelled. I'll dig a bit further to find more informations.

Comment: @Ced most probably it has to do something with interceptor